# How to search data using OleDbDataReader in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datareader

With ms access as the database storage software. 
And if you know of other ways on how to read data base on a certain criteria and displaying the results that meets the criteria.

Comment: You should ask on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question. How about adding some details on what you are searching for and in what column(s).

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to create a SQL query that does all the data searching/filtering/ordering on the database so you don't have to do it in code.

Doing it that way, all you have to do is iterate through the results in the `DataReader`.

If you're unfamiliar with SQL, [here is a good place to get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826%28SQL.90%29.aspx).